# Bootstrap 2 - outdated content?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems, twitter-bootstrap, auto-update

I have installed bootstrap to my Rails 3.2 app this way (through Gemfile):

> gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails", "~> 2.0"

When I this morning came to computer, so the app looked  else - was changed the content of bootstrap, for example in **input** I used the class **xlarge**, now I must to use **input-xlarge** - and the changes is more.

Other stuff, the CSS class **page-header** is currently not in the bootstrap (when I take a look into **http://localhost:3000/assets/twitter/bootstrap.css?body=1**)

So I would like to ask you - bootstrap was automatically updated or what happend? Or, how can I fix it? Tried `bundle update`, but the same...

When I take a look into the header of **bootstrap.css**, so there is

```
/*!
 * Bootstrap @VERSION
 *
 * Copyright 2012 Twitter, Inc
 * Licensed under the Apache License v2.0
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Designed and built with all the love in the world @twitter by @mdo and @fat.
 * Date: @DATE
 */
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like [the gem was updated to Bootstrap 2](https://rubygems.org/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails) and you're still using Bootstrap 1 syntax. Running `bundle update` would exactly do the opposite of what you want because will update the gem to the latest version.

You need to use a previous gem version.

```
gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails", "~> 1.0"
```

Then run `$ bundle install` again. Needless to say, you should upgrade your syntax as soon as possible to take advantage of Bootstrap 2.

Comment: thank you, already works me. But that mean, that when is released a new version of bootstrap, so the old ones are not supported? Exist any way, how to "lock" the version, that I use in my app?

Comment: You lock the version defining the version you want to use, exactly how I showed you in my answer.